# Sony Spresenseのシリアルモニタで文字化けが発生する

Tags: spresense

Sony Spresenseのサンプルスケッチ「gnss.ino」を書込みGNSS受信動作をシリアルモニタで確認しようとしましたが文字化けが発生します。
何か設定を変更する必要があるのでしょうか？

Comment: この記事 [SPRESENSEでGPS測位](https://blog.goo.ne.jp/pearlwing/e/0aff4db27bdf36f3ab15371c6c6868b2) だとシリアルモニタの「通信ボーレートを115200bpsに変更」しているようですが。

Comment: ボーレートを変更したら直りました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

シリアルモニタから「通信ボーレート」の値を変更してみてください。

**参考:**

[SPRESENSEでGPS測位](https://blog.goo.ne.jp/pearlwing/e/0aff4db27bdf36f3ab15371c6c6868b2)

> - <ツール>　→　<シリアルモニタ> を選択
> - 通信ボーレートを `115200bps` に変更する

---

*この投稿は @kunif さんのコメント の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*